# Splitting a pdf into multiple pages with Adobe Pro

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

another piece of software allowed my to export my document into a pdf, my desired format for sharing. However, the document is quite long, and when I print it, the entire thing is printed as a tiny stripe in the center of the page.

is there a way to zoom the print out, so that it fills the page width?  Maybe some way to add page breaks so that it prints like any other document?

Thanks in advance for your help, guys!

Comment: Is your original PDF only 1 page?

Comment: Sounds like your pdf is all one page, comprising of all the pages of your document... which is an odd way for an application to produce a pdf. Was it broken up in separate pages in your original document? If so, you may need to check the Export settings there first. As it stands, there's really no good way print the document you have, if it's all consolidated into one page.

Comment: My pdf is of a dashboard and is generated by a web tool.  It does not have any pages in the original.

Comment: Not sure how you would split a 1 page PDF in Acrobat but if you had Illustrator you could create various artboards and then save as a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If your original document is one big  raster image you may have to use Photoshop to create separate pages, in users print dialog they can print as a spread. Or, if you cannot break up the image make sure you create a custom size for your pdf so it matches your image size, and users will have to print tiled format. Can't see any other way around it..
ellen